# Stripe : Hidden stripe fields show validation error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, stripe-payments

I have a form, Where i am showing the current cards of `stripe customer`, As well i have an option of new card payment fields.

```
<form>
    //inputs
    .......
    <div class="row" id="payementForm" style="display: none">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="card-element">
            </label>
            <div id="card-element">
            </div>
            <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
          </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**When i submit the form with the user using the existing card, The hidden field of stripe shows validation errors.**

I am curious that why its showing validation errors, **They are hidden.
Is there anyway around **

Comment: Validation occurs at client end or at the server end?

Comment: @jagad89 Validations are from the stripe end, Its server based as well as client based.

Comment: What are the actual errors that you get?

Comment: @karllekko I am not getting any fatal errors, If you read the question, The form have stripe fields and if a user goes with the current card to be charged then the fields must be empty, And as well by default the fields are hidden too, But still i gives me the validation errors.

Comment: @Gammer Could you create a snippet with your full code showing the problem? I'm also not clear what you mean by 'existing card'/'current card'.

Comment: In the `<form>` do you have multiple rows with `id="payementForm"`?

Comment: @Kyslik No i have only one.

Comment: @Gammer so the issue is that when you hide the form `payementForm` you are still seeing the text from the `card-errors`, or something else? I've tried to replicate it and that doesn't happen to me. Could you try to put together a full running snippet to demonstrate the issue?